# Reading a line of a txt file in assets

Tags: java, android, text

I have a text file placed in assets and I want to read one line of it at a time. My problem is that I do not know how to access the file in Activity, and then once I access it, how would I go about only selecting one line?

If keeping the txt file in assets is a bad idea, where should I put it for easier access?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open assests, you'll need to call

```
<context>.getAssets().open(<your file>);
```

`<context>` is your activity, so if this is in your `onCreate`, then it would be `this`. That call returns an inputstream, which you can then handle however you please.

I don't see how it would be a particularly bad idea to keep your text file there, depends on what you're using that text file for.

Comment: Thank you! This coupled with code to change inputstream to bufferedreader and then using my method to read a line of a bufferedreader worked perfectly!

Comment: Hmm, actually I'm running into a bit of trouble now. What if I want to put this code into an onClick for a button? When I try to, it says that it's undefined for OnClickListener. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, it says The method getAssets() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Strange, it should be ok if you do a this.getAssets() inside the onClick method.

Comment: Weird that it didn't work, however I create a static method and called it onClick and that worked. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You could use <activity>.this.getAssets() where <activity> is the activity which hosts the OnClickListener

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet I use to prepopulate tables in my RSS feed reader. You can use it as a track for your needs.

In `res/raw/` I have file `feeds.txt`. The file is referenced is code like `R.raw.feeds`.

```
    final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
    InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.feeds);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 8192);

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             //make the use you want with "line"
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading sample feeds.");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it with the file in res/raw, but I think I'm just going to keep it in assets for now!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Make a new method for example readMyFile().
It must looks like this:

```
private String readMyFile(File file) throws IOException {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();
     String line;

     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        txt.append(line);
        txt.append("\n");
}

reader.close();
return txt.toString();
```

Paste it to your code, and use the method (readMyFile([the file what you want to read in assets]).

Hope it helps.